# Color tiles (triangles) of a categorical ternary/simplex plot according to numeric values

Tags: r, ggplot2, categorical-data, ternary, ggtern

I have a data set with combinations of 3 categorical variables (each with 6 classes) and a continuous value (ranging from 0 to 1) that belongs to these class combinations. In R, this data looks like this (example data):

```
grid <- expand.grid(letters[1:6], letters[1:6], letters[1:6])[, 3:1]
grid$vals <- runif(nrow(grid), 0, 1)
```

Now I'm going to visualize this data. My plan was to create a ternary (syn. simplex) plot for the three categorical variables ("Var3", "Var2" and "Var1") and color the 216 triangles belonging to each combination of categories according to the values in the variable "vals". It would be great if the color code would range from red (value of 0) via white (value of 0.5) to blue (value of 1).

Unfortunately I already struggle a lot creating a simple ternary plot with 6 categories per variable. Thus, I'd be very happy if you'd recommend a solution. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: look at `scale_colour_gradientn()` note the n at the end, since you want a 3-colour scale.  Since your middle colour is white you may get away with the simpler `scale_colour_gradient2()`.  Reference here: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_gradient.html

Comment: take a look at this: http://www.ggtern.com/d/2.2.2/geom_tri_tern.html

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen, @Mark: Thanks to both of you. However, This doesn't work for example: ```ggtern(grid, aes(x = Var3, y = Var2, z = Var1, fill = vals)) +
  geom_tri_tern(bins = 6, aes(fill = vals)) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = c("red", "white", "blue"))```

Comment: ah, it would be `scale_fill_gradientn()` then, as a fill-scale.  Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
# adapted from the documentation example: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_gradient.html

library(ggtern)
set.seed(1)

library(tidyverse)
library(ggtern)
grid %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Var"), as.numeric)) %>%
  ggtern(aes(Var1, Var2, Var3)) +
   geom_tri_tern(bins=10,aes(fill=after_stat(count))) + 
   scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("red", "white", "blue"), 
                        values = c(0, 0.5, 1))
```

[image: ternary plot]

Comment: I used the example's data because it makes it simpler. I can add a bit on translating from the ordinal (?) data in your example to the numerical data if you would find it helpful

Comment: Thanks a lot! I hope I'll figure out myself how to make it looking how I want it to be. Will post it here if I'll succeed

Comment: updated it to have the 3 colour gradient!

Comment: Thanks. I think the problem I encounter is this: I already have some "count" data (ok, it's probabilities). However, as far as I understand it, your code "counts" the number of points thatfall into each triangle ... Working on it.

Comment: ah so are you wanting to find the sum of the probabilities for each triangle?

Comment: Not really. I already have some probabilities for a particular occurence (that's the numbers in the variable "vals" in my example code). I want every 6 * 6 * 6 times colored according to these probabilities (from red - white - blue. Something like this: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DT8qw1dV4AA046c.jpg (but with only 6 triangles per axis) and of course a different color code.

Comment: updated it again!